# Subir más de una imagen con Sirius Upload

Tags: php

Tengo este problema desde hace unas horas, estoy siguiendo la librería de [Sirius](http://www.sirius.ro/php/), tanto Validation como Upload:

```
$rootfolder = realpath('img/articulos/');

$slide = new UploadHandlerAggregate($rootfolder); 
$thumbnail = new UploadHandlerAggregate($rootfolder); 

$slide->addHandler('slide', $rootfolder); //<- aqui los errores
$thumbnail->addHandler('thumbnail', $rootfolder); //<- aqui los errores

$upload = new Sirius\Upload\HandlerAggregate();
$upload->addHandler('slide', $slide);
$upload->addHandler('thumbnail', $thumbnail);

if (($images->isValid())) {
   $eventos->slide = $images['slide']->name;
   $eventos->thumbnail = $images['thumbnail']->name;
   $eventos->save();
   $images->confirm();
}
```

Estoy tratando de subir más de una imagen. Todo anda bien subiendo una, pero para subir más de un archivo varía un poco. El detalle es que me dice el host que `UploadHandlerAggregate::addHandler()` debe ser una instancia. Y ahí está mi bloqueo.

Comment: Ese código parece que es para una sola imagen, ¿cómo lo haces para procesar múltiples imágenes? ¿lo pones en un bucle o algo? También sería genial si pudieras poner el mensaje exacto que sale cuando falla. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 0):

Para subir varias imagenes debes de crear una instancia de `Handler` donde indiques las reglas que van a seguir las imagenes, luego una instancia de `HandlerAggregate`, el cual tendra la instancia previamente creada.

```
use Sirius\Upload\Handler as UploadHandler;
use Sirius\Upload\HandlerAggregate as UploadHandlerAggregate;

$uploadHandler = new UploadHandler('/path/to/local_folder');

// set up the validation rules
$uploadHandler->addRule('extension', ['allowed' => 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'], '{label} should be a valid image (jpg, jpeg, png)', 'Profile picture');
$uploadHandler->addRule('size', ['max' => '20M'], '{label} should have less than {max}', 'Profile picture');
$uploadHandler->addRule('imageratio', ['ratio' => 1], '{label} should be a sqare image', 'Profile picture');
// una vez hecho eso generas una instancia de UploadHandlerAggregate
$uploadHandlerAggregate = new UploadHandlerAggregate();
// y agregas el manejador de las imagenes
$uploadHandlerAggregate->addHandler('picture', $uploadHandler);
// procesas los archivos
$result = $uploadHandlerAggregate->process($_FILES);


if ($result->isValid()) {
    // do something with the image like attaching it to a model etc
    try {
        $profile->picture = $result['picture']->name;
        $profile->save();
        $result->confirm(); // this will remove the .lock files
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // something wrong happened, we don't need the uploaded files anymore
        $result->clear();
        throw $e;
    }
} else {
    // image was not moved to the container, where are error messages
    $messages = $result->getMessages();
}
```

http://www.sirius.ro/php/sirius/upload/simple_example.html

http://www.sirius.ro/php/sirius/upload/upload_aggregator.html